# Can polychloroprene further react

Tags: polymers

Chloroprene undergoes radical polymerisation to form polychloroprene.

Chloroprene is a special structure since it has two carbon-carbon double bonds and it turns out that polychloroprene also has one carbon-carbon double bond.

In both addition polymerisation and radical polymerisation, the carbon-carbon double bonds in monomers are broken to form the polymers.

I wonder, if the carbon-carbon double bonds in polychloroprene can further undergo:

(i) Addition reactions

(ii) Addition/ radical polymerisation

Comment: It certainly can, that's like the main point of using it in the first place.